# 3x analog signal multiplier

Tags: signal, differential-amplifier, multiplier, analog-multiplier

I was looking for sin(x) in, sin(3x) out. I am aware of PLL, diode, and AD632 multipliers. Most are either squarers for sin(2x) or pure sine or amplitude multipliers.

I saw the sin(a+b) identity and thought that if I take the input, square for sin(2x), differentiate for cos(x), and square that (AD632 or similar) for cos(2x), that I could populate the sin(a+b) identity with some multipliers and a summer. I am aware that without compensation the differentiator will be noisy. But before I start to draw it up I wanted to ask if anyone sees major pitfalls. Desmos shows the overlay to be correct, "in theory."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you have a signal of the form sin(x) where x is some unknown signal, there isn't really any way to "differentiate for cos(x)." Are you familiar with the triple-angle formula which describes sin(3x) completely in terms of sin(x)?

Comment: A cos(x) differentiator is really just a 90° phase offset. Most differentiators add an input resistor to null the phase error, but I had hoped to use it. In all, the triple angle formula will solve it. Thanks you all very much.

Comment: Well, in analog electronics, a differentiator gives you the derivative with respect to time, not the derivative with respect to x, right? In order to obtain d(sin x)/dx (which is cos x), it seems like you would have to do (d(sin x)/dt) / (dx/dt). The differentiator would give you d(sin x)/dt, but it seems like there's no way to get dx/dt, so you can't do it.

Answer (score 5):

Recall the triple angle formula $$\sin (3\,\theta)=3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta.$$

Two four-quadrant multipliers and some fixed gain stages solve that problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffmEF5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Waveforms (blue-output, orange-input):

[image]

The multipliers work with input and output signals of the same amplitude - that's often the way to get best performance out of them.

Comment: Slick, concise, and build able. I like this.

Comment: I like that it can be done with multipliers, but not just squaring, and without the log/anti-log loop (offset issues). Thank you very much !!!!!